# Dynamically change details section height in Crystal Reports

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2003 and i want to automatically change details section height (resize it) if one of the fields is empty.
My report looks like this:
'-----------------------------------'
[Product] [Weight] [Quantity] 
[Note]
'-----------------------------------'

So if [Note] is empty, i want to auto fit details section, so that it looks like:
'-----------------------------------'
[Product] [Weight] [Quantity]
'-----------------------------------'

Because now i am getting extra free space, which i don't want and it looks like:
'-----------------------------------'
[Product] [Weight] [Quantity]

'-----------------------------------'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a new sub-section; so you have two details sections.  **Details-A** and **Details-B**.

Place [Product] [Weight] [Quantity] in **Details-A** and place [Note] in **Details-B** below.

Then in the section expert, select **Details-B** and click the formula button.  Use a formula to suppress the section when [Note] is not populated; something like:

```
if isnull([Note]) or [Note]='' then true else false
```

This will suppress the note section if its blank; thus keeping your details section nicely sized.

Comment: thx it helped. I typed in formula field "if({tblOrders.note}="") then formula=true"

Comment: You should be able to achieve the same results (without the suppression formula) simply by enabling (checking) Detail-B section's 'suppress blank section' option.

Comment: @craig is right; however I have had experience of this not working in CR version 9.  So I always hard-code it.